# How long does it generally take to release a soundtrack?

Tags: anime-production, k-project

Essentially, I want to know how long it normally takes for soundtracks to be released after an anime's release. Are the soundtracks always released?

The main reason I ask is because I want to know when we can expect 
**K: Return of Kings'** soundtrack to release. It came out in 2015, and I still haven't heard any news about its soundtrack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't answer your broader question, but [the *K: Return of Kings* soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/57125) is scheduled for [release on April 27, 2016](http://www.animate-onlineshop.jp/pn/pd/1384318/).

> Are the soundtracks always released?

Not always, but I'd guesstimate that 80-90% of anime have soundtracks released at some point. Those that don't are mostly shows targeted at children, who are probably not likely to buy soundtracks.

> Essentially, I want to know how long it normally takes for soundtracks to be released after an anime's release.

This can range anywhere from "before the show is even done airing" (e.g. [*Shokugeki no Soma*'s first soundtrack album](http://vgmdb.net/album/52352)) to "not until season 2" (e.g. [*Nisekoi*'s first soundtrack album](http://vgmdb.net/album/52068)) to "yeah, we were *going* to release it soon, but lolno too bad" (e.g. [*Tokyo Ghoul*](http://vgmdb.net/album/46608) - granted, they did put out [an actual album](http://vgmdb.net/album/50263) half a year later).

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

- Absolute Duo took about a little less than 6 months
- Fairy Tail Original Sound Collection 2 came in about 4 months after